# how to uncheck/check a primeng checkbox manually

Tags: javascript, html, angular, checkbox, primeng

### html

```
<p-checkbox name="showLinkedRisksOnly" id="showLinkedRisksOnlyChkBx" 
   label="Show Only Linked Risks" binary="true" (click)="showOnlyLinkedRisks($event)"
   [ngModel]="showLinkedRisksOnly" ></p-checkbox>
```

### typescript

```
showOnlyLinkedRisks($event){
  if(condition){
    this.showLinkedRisksOnly = !this.showLinkedRisksOnly;
  }
}
```

I am trying to change the state of checkbox back to before it was checked/unchecked based on condition. But for some reason the checkbox and model get out of sync when I do change the value of this.showLinkedRisksOnly.
Is it possible to achive

Comment: Your code looks fine, I'm pretty sure the error can be found elsewhere in the code

Comment: Could you elaborate more? ur code seems working.

Comment: i am changing the value of model, but its not updating in UI

Comment: Try `[(ngModel)]` instead of `[ngModel]` .

Comment: Provide a stackblitz

Comment: Use banana inbox instead. [(ngModel)]

Comment: i want to control the value of ngmodel inside my component, don't want it be controlled by ui interaction

Answer (score 2):

### Method 1 - Handle ngModelChange + trigger change detection

To make the checkbox readonly, you can handle the `ngModelChange` event:

```
<p-checkbox ...
  [ngModel]="showLinkedRisksOnly" 
  (ngModelChange)="showOnlyLinkedRisks($event)">
</p-checkbox>
```

and follow these steps in the event handler:

1. Set the new value
2. If the checkbox is readonly

   3. Trigger change detection
   4. Put the original value back

```
constructor(private cd: ChangeDetectorRef) { }

showOnlyLinkedRisks(value) {
  this.showLinkedRisksOnly = value;    // Set the new value
  if (!this.condition) {               // If the checkbox is readonly
    this.cd.detectChanges();           // Trigger change detection
    this.showLinkedRisksOnly = !value; // Put the original value back
  }
}
```

See [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-primeng-p-checkbox-issue-ydbxjd) for a demo.

---

### Method 2 - Two-way binding + disable control

An alternative method is to use two-way binding, and to disable the control to prevent changes:

```
<p-checkbox ...
  [(ngModel)]="showLinkedRisksOnly" 
  [disabled]="!condition">
</p-checkbox>
```

See [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-primeng-p-checkbox-issue-fxkgot) for a demo.

Answer (score 2):

First, binding onChange event instead of click event.
Then add checkbox instance to event

```
<p-checkbox name="showLinkedRisksOnly" #something id="showLinkedRisksOnlyChkBx" label="Show Only Linked Risks" binary="true" (click)="showOnlyLinkedRisks($event, something)" [ngModel]="showLinkedRisksOnly"></p-checkbox>
```

And in typescript

```
showOnlyLinkedRisks(event, control) {
    if (false) {
      control.checked = false;
    } else { this.showLinkedRisksOnly = event.checked; }
}
```

Sorry for my bad english!